# Session object in shopping cart

Tags: jsp, session, e-commerce, shopping-cart

In your experience, is using the Session object to maintain a shopping cart a satisfactory approach for an E-Commerce application, if Java Server Pages are used?

Comment: Quote from the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask): `If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here.`.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle seems to think so - http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/javaeetutorial6.pdf

Here's a snippet under the "Maintaining Client State" section...

> Many applications require that a series of requests from a client be
>   associated with one another. For example, a web application can save
>   the state of a user’s shopping cart across requests. Web-based
>   applications are responsible for maintaining such state, called a
>   session, because HTTP is stateless. To support applications that need
>   to maintain state, Java Servlet technology provides an API for
>   managing sessions and allows several mechanisms for implementing
>   sessions.